# A sticky/fixed header won't work onscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following code for a [sticky header](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/news/index.html), but the scroll makes the content jump up the page and it's not a smooth transition. The #top-nav-wrapper barely scrolls when the fixed header below is activated.

The top nav should scroll up naturally and the search bar should remain.

2 scripts produce the same results, as does cloning:

```
<script>
$(document).scroll( function() {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( value > 48 ) {
        $(".header").css("position", "fixed");
        $("body").css("padding-top", "90px");
    } else {
        $(".header").css("position", "relative");
        $("body").css("padding-top", "0");
    }
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var height = $('.header').outerHeight();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(this).scrollTop() >= height)
            {
                $('.header').css('position','fixed');
                $('body').css('padding-top',height+'px');
            }
            else if($(this).scrollTop() <= height)
            {
                $('.header').css('position','static');
                $('body').css('padding-top','0');
            }
    });
    $(window).scroll();
});
</script>
```

The 48 value is the height of the #top-nav-wrapper, plus it has a box-shadow.

The .header class with the search bar is what should remain.

The basic html:

```
<div class="headerWrapper">
    <div id="top-nav-wrapper"></div>
        <div class="header"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
  background: #EEE;
}

#top-nav-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #B8B8B8;
  z-index: 2001;
  background: #EEE;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 90px;
  z-index: 2000;
  background: #EEE;
  height: 90px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #C4C4C4;
}
```

I tried the following suggestion, but it's the same effect as before:

```
<script>
        $(window).scroll( function() {
            var value = $(this).scrollTop();
            var $body = $('body');
            var docked = $body.hasClass('docked');    

            if ( value > 48 ) {
                if( !docked ) {
                    $body.addClass('docked');
                }
            } else {
                if( docked ) {
                    $body.removeClass('docked');
                }
            }
        });
        </script>
```

Some have suggested the z-index is higher on the #top-nav-wrapper, but this has nothing to do with it and also just hides the problem - plus there's opacity on the header so it shows underneath.

I need a real solution to fixing what should be so simple; not a cover up.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem might be that the script is being called every time you scroll (even a little bit) so it's causing the page to re-render. That is - as you scroll, the event is fired many times, and it's confusing the page.

You might get a more smooth effect if you allow the scroll event to call another function which works out how long it was since the last time it was called, and exits unless there has been a time lag.

I have had this situation before myself, but not with jquery. somethign like this ...

```
var lastTime=0; // hasn't been called yet - note it's a global variable
$(document).scroll( function() {
   myOnScroll();
}
);


function myOnScroll() {
   var nowTime= new Date().getTime(); // current time
   var cutoffTime= .03; [you decide a number of milliseconds ? maybe about 3 times a second ? probably a xcase of trying values to see what works best];
   if (nowTime-lastTime < cutoffTime)  { return;} // quit if it's too early
   lastTime=nowTime; // make a note of the last time we did this
   // do the scrolling stuff here .. 
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I guess you could put it all in one function though.

Comment: Hmm - If you look at this example : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_scroll    the event is fired many times as you scroll